# Many people do bad things but live long and prosperous lives. How?

Tags: karma, life

If theory of Karma is correct , then how do many people who do bad things live long , rich and prosperous lives.

Comment: because karma spans multiple births. you also see children born disabled, with cancer etc. ever wonder why ?

Comment: @mar But many people say that you suffer deeds of your karma in this birth only. Like Duryodhan death occurred because he had asked Draupdi to sit on his thighs , thus his thighs got weakned and he was killed.
So, How is is determined for which deed we will have to suffer in this very birth for which deed in next birth .

Comment: yes you can get consequences in same birth also. or you can get in next birth or 7 births later. only bhagavan knows when and how to give results.

Comment: How it is determined or meted out  is known only to the Lord. In the Brahma Sutras. duplicate question.

Comment: if you take life of pandavas and life of duryodhana.. till duryodhanas death.. he lived life of prince and he need not suffer forest dwelling and he need not serve anybody..but his entire life is miserable because of his taught of eny and unhappiness about the pandavas gaining.. making ones life miserable or happier its internal how each one feels. like one can beg and live be happy not worry a thing. but richer person need to sustain wealth and future and worry thousand thing.

Comment: @PrasannaR Worrying is not a bad thing . Every person is worried about something.